# Matlab: turn 2d struct array of scalars to a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, struct

I'm writing code in which I have a 2D struct array (`organism = 10x10 struct`), one of its fields consists completely of scalars, and I want to extract all of these scalars and put them into a matrix.
I tried putting it in square brackets, but instead of giving me a rectangular matrix, it gave me a long row matrix;

```
>>    [organism(1:3,1:3).fitness]

ans =

-5   990   493   492    -5    -8   994    -5   -10
```

Again, I was hoping to receive

```
-5    990   493
492   -5    -8
994   -5    -10
```

I tried `vertcat(organism(1:3,1:3).fitness)`, but as could be expected, it just gave me one column. I'm hoping to do this with no for loops, as this will eventually be the whole of a struct array with a size at minimum 50x50.
Is there a way to turn a field that's all scalars in a 2D struct array into a matrix with the same dimensions?

(I won't have any trouble with 40x60 turning into 60x40; I don't expect to have any difficulty transposing the matrix I get out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reshape:

```
scalar_matrix = reshape([organism.fitness], size(organism));
```